# How to connect to a MSSQL database on a remote (windows) server from python?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have the following information about the remote server.

- IP address
- Database user name
- Database password
- Database name

I can even connect to the remote server using azure data studio, running on my Laptop, which is running on Ubuntu 20.04.

However, this is my requirement

- Connect to the MSSQL database programmatically from python
- Simply write a pandas dataframe as a table.

I tried using pyodbc, but whenever I try `pyodbc.connect()`, I get an error saying

```
InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Is there some other library I should use instead of pyodbc? Here is my sample code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8    
import pyodbc
credential='DRIVER=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server;SERVER=192.168.101.56;DATABASE=DEMAND_FORECAST;ENCRYPT=yes;UID=della;PWD=strong;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
pyodbc.connect(str=credential) # Throwing error
# InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default 
# driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

pyodbc.drivers()
# ['ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server']
```

Comment: Sounds like you haven't installed the drivers; have you followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: @Larnu yes, I have added unixodbc, unixodbc-dev via apt repository, and pyodbc as a pip module. Some readings led me to believe I have to supply some data source name to pyodbc, but not clear on what exactly is that. Is that the ip address of where the server is running?

Comment: That connection string doesn't look right; you can't provide a username and password *and* use a trusted connection; it's either SQL Authentication or Windows Authentication, not *both*.

Comment: Also, per the documentation, it should be `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}`.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for getting back. So I have an ip address, user name, password and database name.  I am getting the driver name by calling the ```drivers()``` method of ```pyodbc``` module. So given these parameters, is there is a standard python function that can spit out the connection string, or is it possible for you to guide how to write that? I am new to MSSQL, but such a long hardcoded string reeks of code-smell and a bug waiting to happen it seems. Also, my laptop is using Ubuntu, and the server is on windows. So can the password be called _windows_ authentication then?

Comment: *"So can the password be called windows authentication then?"* I don't understand this sentence.

Comment: Parametrising a connection string is possible, yes, just concatenate your parameters to the connection string (like shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16#connect)). How you parametrise those parts is up to you and a *very* different question to what you're asking; which appears to be typographical errors (the missing braces (`{}`).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you need to do something like:
Porbably you are missing the `"Driver={SQL Server}` or you need to change it to something else

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};" 
                                  "Server=" your server + ";"
                                  "Database=" your db+ ";"
                                  "UID=" +your uid + ";"
                                  "PWD=" + your PWD
                                  )
```